# JanusGraph : Reindexing using MapReduceIndexManagement is not working

Tags: mapreduce, lucene, janusgraph

I am using Janusgraph 0.2.0 and Hbase with lucene as index backend. I am facing issue while Reindexing using MapReduceIndexManagement

Below is Error trace -

```
    Error=java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the location for replica 0
    at org.janusgraph.hadoop.MapReduceIndexManagement$FailedJobFuture.get(MapReduceIndexManagement.java:298)
    at org.janusgraph.hadoop.MapReduceIndexManagement$FailedJobFuture.get(MapReduceIndexManagement.java:268)
    at com.inn.foresight.core.generic.utils.CustomDataSource.addMapreduceReIndex(CustomDataSource.java:188)
    at com.inn.foresight.core.generic.utils.CustomDataSource.main(CustomDataSource.java:163)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the location for replica 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.allTableRegions(MetaScanner.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HRegionLocator.getAllRegionLocations(HRegionLocator.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSizeCalculator.init(RegionSizeCalculator.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSizeCalculator.<init>(RegionSizeCalculator.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:237)
    at org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.hbase.HBaseBinaryInputFormat.getSplits(HBaseBinaryInputFormat.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at org.janusgraph.hadoop.scan.HadoopScanRunner.runJob(HadoopScanRunner.java:138)
    at org.janusgraph.hadoop.MapReduceIndexManagement.updateIndex(MapReduceIndexManagement.java:187)
    ... 2 more
```

And My janusgraph properties are below

```
 storage.backend = hbase
storage.hostname =  localhost
storage.port = 2181
storage.hbase.ext.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort = 2181
storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent = /hbase-unsecure
query.fast-property = true
storage.hbase.table = Master9
storage.read-time = 200000
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
index.search.backend=lucene
index.search.directory=/home/ist/jIndexFolder
```

and Here is my code

```
JGraphUtil jGraphUtil = new JGraphUtil();
        JanusGraph jGraph = jGraphUtil.openGraphInstance();
        JanusGraphManagement management;
        JanusGraphTransaction newTransaction;
        jGraphUtil.closeOtherInstances();
        newTransaction = jGraph.newTransaction();
        management = jGraph.openManagement();
        JanusGraphIndex graphIndex = management.getGraphIndex("bySrcEName");
        MapReduceIndexManagement mrim = new MapReduceIndexManagement(jGraph);
        try {
            mrim.updateIndex(graphIndex, SchemaAction.REINDEX).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | BackendException e) {
            System.out.println("Error=" + Utils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
```

Please any one check and let me know how can I perform reindex in JanusGraph. Any example of reindexing using MapReduceIndexManagement will be appreciated

Comment: Hi, Did you got the solution? I'm also facing the same problem.